# ResolveAll not working

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a code which look something like this.  When trying to do a  `ResolveAll` I expected every type registered with the `IParserType` to yielded from the container instance. But I didn't get any instance from `Unity`. Am I assuming or doing something wrong here.

```
public class ResolveAllDemo
{
    public ResolveAllDemo()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
        container.RegisterType<IParser, SuperParser>();
        container.RegisterType<IParser, DefaultParser>();
        container.RegisterType<IParser, BasicParser>();
        //   container.RegisterType<Crawler>();
        container.RegisterType<IParserFactory, UnityParserFactory>();

        foreach (var registeredMember in container.ResolveAll<IParser>())
        {
            LoggingUtility.LogerInstance.Logger.Write(registeredMember);
        }
    }

    #region Resolve Demo

    public interface IParserFactory
    {
        IEnumerable<IParser> BuildParsers();
    }

    public class UnityParserFactory : IParserFactory
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;

        public UnityParserFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IParser> BuildParsers()
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll<IParser>();
        }
    }

    public class DefaultParser : IParser
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DefaultParser";
        }
    }

    public class BasicParser : IParser
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "BasicParser";
        }
    }

    public class SuperParser : IParser
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "SuperParser";
        }
    }

    public interface IParser
    {
    }

    #endregion Resolve Demo
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are not registering 3 different implementations of `IParser`. You create one default mapping `IParser` -> `SuperParser` and then overwrite it with `IParser` -> `DefaultParser` and then you overwrite it again with `IParser` -> `BasicParser`.

If you want to register all three of them you have to provide named registrations like

```
container.RegisterType<IParser, SuperParser>("Super");
container.RegisterType<IParser, DefaultParser>("Default");
container.RegisterType<IParser, BasicParser>("Basic");
```

In addition `ResolveAll` does not include the default mapping (the one without a name). It only resolves those mappings of `IParser` that were registered as named mappings.

Comment: Do you know if the fact that the default is not returned is by design or is it a bug?

Comment: @NicolasIrisarri Apart from the fact that it's in the codebase since at least v1.2 I believe it's by design. You can easily work around it if you register the default mapping again with a name (e.g. "default").

Comment: this really is valuable information. unity behaving this way does not make any sense

Comment: I think Unity really should throw an exception instead of just owerwriting or even better make default behavior being Unity registering the registered type as name.

Comment: @JonasStensved Other containers remember multiple registrations as default and use that to create chains of objects at resolve-time. Unity overwrites that registration. Different containers, different behaviors. But you can always expand Unity to match your preferences.

Comment: Unity really is a terrible POS

Answer (score 17):

You need to register your parsers with a name, if you want to resolve all Parsers from the container.

Here´s the update code from your constructor:

```
public ResolveAllDemo() 
{

  var container = new UnityContainer();

  container.RegisterType<IParser, SuperParser>("SuperParser");
  container.RegisterType<IParser, DefaultParser>("DefaultParser");
  container.RegisterType<IParser, BasicParser>("BasicParser");

  container.RegisterType<IParserFactory, UnityParserFactory>();

  foreach (var registeredMember in container.ResolveAll<IParser>())
  {
     LoggingUtility.LogerInstance.Logger.Write(registeredMember);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

There is no need for the following code, cause the container registers itself during construction of the container.

```
container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
// not needed cause UnityContainer registers itself on construction
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer really saved me a lot of debugging today!