# Unity Resolution fails when Singleton is registered with named parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following class and interface definitions:

```
interface IView { ... }

interface IViewA : IView { ... }
interface IViewB : IView { ... }

class ViewA : IViewA { ... }
class ViewB : IViewB { ... }

class Controller
{
     public Controller(IViewA view) { ... }
}
```

And I register them in the unity container like this:

```
unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<IViewA, ViewA>("TheTestViewA");
unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<IViewB, ViewB>("TheTestViewB");
unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<Controller>();
```

However when I then request the instance of the controller, unity throws an exception.

```
unityContainer.Resolve<Controller>();
```

`Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type IViewA.`

It seems that it wants to construct the interface and not the class. I also found out, that when I omit the naming parameter "TheTestViewA" it works fine. However I need that parameter because later on I need to `container.ResolveAll<IView>()` which only works when the mapping has a name.  ( [ResolveAll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124629/resolveall-not-working) )

Comment: Is there only one concrete of IView (the "View" you provide?) or other concretes of IView?  Why do you need to call ResolveAll?

Comment: @granadaCoder, yes there are several implementations of IView, i will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: So I would suggest that you do not use the "ServiceLocator" pattern...where you pull out the (n concretes) from the IoC container.  But rather you inject them as needed. Please look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402064/using-a-strategy-and-factory-pattern-with-dependency-injection/52435195#52435195    The 3 concretes I have are disambiguated......but does not use ServiceLocator.

Comment: Also (next to my answer) read the "Steven" answer.....he outlines the why very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is confusing, but what happens is that Unity can't find a registration for `IView`. For it to be able to inject an `IView` into `Controller`, it requires a nameless registration for `IView`, but all it has is a named registration (`TheTestViewA`).

Since a registration for `IView` is missing, Unity assumes `IView` is a concrete type and tries to instantiate it. But `IView` has no constructors (because its an interface), hence the exception.

You can try the following code instead:

```cs
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<ViewA>();
unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<IViewA, ViewA>();
unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<IViewB, ViewB>();
            
unityContainer.RegisterFactory<IView>("A", c => c.Resolve<IViewA>(), new SingletonLifetimeManager());
unityContainer.RegisterFactory<IView>("B", c => c.Resolve<IViewB>(), new SingletonLifetimeManager());

unityContainer.RegisterSingleton<Controller>();
```

Comment: Thanks, that will avoid the exception, but later when calling `ResolveAll<IView>` I will get an empty list instead of all singletons that implement IView.

Comment: Ha!  I just put the ioc jedi master reference in the comments "See 'Steven' answer".. and here you are!

Comment: The updated solution partially works, but the problem with this is, that it creates two Singletons of ViewA and ViewB, while I want to have only one. i.e. the two registrations should return the same instance of ViewA and ViewB.

Comment: @clamp: I'm sorry about that. Updated my question again. I got confused by how Unity handles deduplication of registrations. It seems t hat named registrations get their own lifetime manager. This is different when making multiple unnamed registrations for the same concrete type (e.g. `c.RegisterSingleton<IA, A>(); c.RegisterSingleton<A>();`). In the latter case you get one instance (e.g. `c.Resolve<A>() == c.Resolve<IA>()`).

Comment: That works, thanks! Just one more question: can the instance of SingletonLifeTimeManager be the same for all factories or does each need its own?

Comment: @clamp: I don't know the answer to your last question.